# Preloader Not Working: AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, video, preload

I'm using this preloader for my Angular app.

https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/jquery.html5loader

The plugin is working properly and I have all my assets labeled in the json file, but there seems to be a problem with the videos. I have 5 full screen videos on separate partials. The screen goes black for about 2 seconds the first time I run through the pages, then they load instantly.

Why is there a pause before the videos play if the content is preloaded?

Why does the plugin not accept absolute URLs?

Here's a sample of how I'm loading my videos:

```
<video id="myVideo" autoplay preload="auto" ng-hide="fullVideo">
    <source ng-src="{{urlwebm}}" type="video/webm">
    <source ng-src="{{urlmp4}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (e, next, previous) {
    $scope.previousPage = $window.location.hash;
});

if($scope.previousPage === '#/home-page') {
    $scope.urlwebm = 'videos/alt/webm/video1.webm';
    $scope.urlmp4 = 'videos/alt/mp4/video1.mp4';
} else {
    $scope.urlwebm = 'videos/webm/altVideo1.webm';
    $scope.urlmp4 = 'videos/mp4/altVideo1.mp4';
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to improve this by loading only the contents I need in each partial. I duplicated the files.json file for each partial and duplicated the script in each partial. It works better now.